# Regular Expression Issue: custom phone number formatting

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using regular expression first time, and I really amazed! well, new discovery always amazement :).
I am using in JavaScript. I am using in following manner;(There are many fields and all are working perfectly fine except this phone formatting)

```
function validate(form) {
    var phone = form.phone.value;
    var phoneRegex = /^(\+|00)\d{2,3}-\d{1,2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/g;
    //Checking 'phone' and its regular expressions  
    if(phone == "") {
      inlineMsg('phone','<strong>Error</strong><br />You must enter phone number.',2);
    return false;
    }
    if(!phone.match(deptRegex)) {
      inlineMsg('phone','<strong>Error</strong><br />Enter valid phone <br />+xxx-x-xxx-xxxx (or) <br />00xxx-x-xxx-xxxx.',2);
    return false;
    }
  return true;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <form name="form" id="form" class="form" onsubmit="validate(this);return false">
<label for="phone">Phone:</label><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
</div>
```

Now I am confuse that I might wrote the wrong expression but I tested it as well. I think I am mistaken to write the expression in JavaScript. Can someone help?

**P.S**The following is the image from a [regular expression online tester](http://www.cyber-reality.com/regexy.html) where I tested the expression.

[image: Test of expression]

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit better?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What is your code where you use the regular expression?

Comment: Your regular expression works: http://regexr.com?30me1 Your problem is likely elsewhere.

Comment: Please don't include pictures, include the code that is not working! (As text, so that we can copy paste it)

Comment: @AbdulAziz - why you combine `^`, `$` and `g` switch?

Comment: @stackoverflow I told you that this is my first time using regular expression and I create this expression with the help of this site http://www.cyber-reality.com/regexy.html

Comment: @JustinMorgan Are you saying that the expression is fine but there is a problem in program?

Comment: Well, it wasn't clear from your question that anything was going wrong. But now that I examine the other code, I can see the problem(s). The regex is fine, but I'll post an answer explaining what else is wrong.

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to run this?

Comment: It produce the inlinemsg of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two problems with your code:

- You don't have a closing `</form>` tag before the last `</div>`
- You're using two different variable names for your regex: `phoneRegex` and `deptRegex`.

Once you correct those problems, the code runs fine. Have a look at it working on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XFWGk/

If that doesn't work, the problem is probably your `inlineMsg` function. I'm not familiar with that one, so make sure you're using it correctly.

Comment: Hey Thank you man... this works, its my silly code re-using mistake. you are right at your both points. I am really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

```
  ^(\+|00)\d{2,3}-\d{1,2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$
```

This matches +nn[n]-n[n]-nnn-nnnn or 0nn[n]-n[n]-nnn-nnnn

What country is that for?

As well as the 00 dial prefix, you might want to also include 011 dial prefix as used from US/Canada.